# Find top 2 highest salary from multiple join tables where salary > N

Tags: sql-server

```
select name
    ,EmployeeTable.id
    ,EmployeeTable.salary
    ,empaddress.StateID
    ,cname
    ,sname
from EmployeeTable 
inner join EmpAddress on EmployeeTable.id=EmpAddress.id 
inner join CityTable on CityTable.ID= EmpAddress.id 
inner join StateTable on CityTable.ID=StateTable.ID
where salary>=15000 order by salary desc
```

Expected output can be `sal >= 15000` with top 2 salaries.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 2`?

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want top 2 employees with top salaries you can use

```
select top 2 name,EmployeeTable.id,EmployeeTable.salary,empaddress.StateID ,cname,sname  
from EmployeeTable inner join EmpAddress on EmployeeTable.id=EmpAddress.id inner join CityTable on CityTable.ID= EmpAddress.id inner join StateTable on 
  CityTable.ID=StateTable.ID

where salary>=15000 order by salary desc
```

else If you want employees who has top 2 salaries can use this one :

```
select name,EmployeeTable.id,EmployeeTable.salary,empaddress.StateID ,cname,sname  
from EmployeeTable inner join EmpAddress on EmployeeTable.id=EmpAddress.id inner join CityTable on CityTable.ID= EmpAddress.id inner join StateTable on 
  CityTable.ID=StateTable.ID

where salary in (select top 2 salary from EmployeeTable order by salary desc )
```